# Vagrant Windows 10 package step removes user profile?

Tags: windows, ssh, virtual-machines, vagrant

I'm building a Vagrant Windows 10 box (using libvirt, based on the workflow documented at here: https://fishilico.github.io/generic-config/windows/vagrant.html). After the VM is ready, I run:

```
vagrant package default --output win10-libvirt.box
```

and then I take the "box" file to another machine and import it using `vagrant add`.

The thing is, as part of the setup I add a key to the user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, but when I start the new box on the second machine - that file is gone. I also tried to add a key to the "administrators' keys" file supported on Microsoft Windows OpenSSH port at `C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys` - but that is also gone when I start the new box - actually the entire `C:\ProgramData\ssh` folder is gone.

Does `vagrant package` cleans the machine configuration folders, and if so - can this be disabled somehow? I couldn't find documentation about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed for me after I added a call to Sysprep followed by shutdown at the end of the provisioning script. I'm not sure if the Sysprep is what was needed or the shutdown - the libvirt shutdown process should be safe enough and watching the libvirt viewer I can see that the VM performs the Windows shutdown process.

I used this command in my `Vagrantfile`:

```ruby
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # ...

    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-'SCRIPT'
& ./run-some-provisioning.ps1
& C:/Windows/System32/sysprep/sysprep.exe /generalize /mode:vm /shutdown
SCRIPT

  # ...
end
```